# URL Not Found (CodeIgniter App on Amazon EC2)

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

After filling and submitting this form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('search'); ?>
        <p>
            <input type="input" name="username" placeholder="@UserName" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>        
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

my submitted data is first processed and the user is supposed to be redirected to **search_page3.php**. Instead, I got this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /search was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.24 (Amazon) Server at
>   ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com Port 80

Here is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {           
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // ...

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $username = $this->input->post('username'); 

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE || $this->val_username($username) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('search_page2');
        }       
        else
        {   
                    // process this data            
            // ...

            $data['data'] = $data;      
            $this->load->view('search_page3', $data);                       
        }               
    }   
    // additional helper functions 
    // ...
}
/* End of file search.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/search.php */
```

I was reading in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348732/uri-routing-not-working-multilingual) that Juan Carlos resolved his URL problem by  setting `AllowOverride` for public_html to `All`. **Just to be on the safe side, my question is, how exactly do I resolve my error?**

Here is my base url from my CodeIgniter `application/config/config.php` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/';
```

Here is my `httpd.conf` from my EC2 instance:

```
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None  
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
```

and here is my `.htaccess` file located `/var/www/html`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: can you show the source code of the html part of the form (`form_open` part)?

Comment: +1 form_open() is a built in CodeIgniter form helper that contains functions that assist in working with forms. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 2):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

If `AllowOverride` is set to `None`, the `.htaccess` file is completely ignored. As such, `index.php` will not be rewritten. Try setting `form_open` to `form_open('index.php/search');` to confirm.

Edit `httpd.conf` and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and restart httpd.

Also, FYI, you aren't redirecting to `search_page3.php`, you are loading a particular view based on a set of conditions. When you say "redirect", I look for `redirect('somepage');`.

Comment: +1 Hi stormdrain. Thanks for your reply. I changed `form_open('search');` to `form_open('index.php/search');` and my view search_page3.php did in fact load (but I got several PHP undefined property errors on search_page3.php, but at least it loaded)! However, when I reverted to `form_open('search'); and edited httpd.conf to `AllowOverride All` and restarted httpd `httpd -k restart` , and reloaded the page, now I'm getting a blank white page. When I reverted to `form_open('index.php/search') again, view search_page3.php loaded with errors.

Comment: btw, yesterday, I set the permissions as
`chmod 777 /var/www/html -R`

Comment: chmod 0755 is probably a more sane setting (777 gives execution privilege which isn't really something you want in your document root). You are working in the root html folder correct? ie you aren't in /var/www/html/codeigniter but in /var/www/html

Comment: +1 yes, i'm working in `/var/www/html/` Is this a bad practice?

Comment: I had originally removed index.php from the urls using mod_rewrite for my WAMP development. But now that I'm working in EC2 and using form_open('index.php/search'); and seeing the index.php in the URLs, I'm a bit confused. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Removing-index.php-in-codeigniter-xampp-for-windows

Comment: No,  standard procedure to be in html root. But it makes a difference to htaccess (RewriteBase). Yeah,  the WAMP stuff should port Ok,  just a matter of aligning everything. Also,  take PT out of htaccess; should just be [L] on the index php line